# Non-coding DNA as a protection to deleterious mutations

Tags: molecular-biology, cancer, mutations

We know that most part of our genome (at least 75 percent) is non-coding DNA. Can it be a way to protect the organism from mutations in important genes, such as the ones which control cellular cycle, as a mutations is much more likely to occur on these parts of the genome?

I've never been told if it could have such a function, and I thought about recently and wasn't able to find a clear answer.

So thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be under the impression that there are a set number mutations per cell, which is not true.  The number of mutations is roughly proportional to the number of bases  — this is because mutations typically happen as a result of errors during DNA replication .<sup>1</sup>  Consequently, more DNA will not protect the coding portions of the genome from mutation.

The reason why mutations appear to be suppressed in coding regions is due to selection.<sup>2</sup>

---

**References**:

1: [Lodish, H., Berk, A., Zipursky, S. L., Matsudaira, P., Baltimore, D., & Darnell, J. (2000). Molecular cell biology 4th edition. *National Center for Biotechnology Information, Bookshelf.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21578/)

2: [Griffiths, A.J.F., Gelbart, W.M., Miller, J.H. and Lewontin, R.C. (1990) The Molecular Basis of Mutation. In: *Modern Genetic Analysis.* W.H. Freeman and Company, New York.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21322/)